# git svn dcommit with TRAILING WHITESPACE discovered in these files errors

Tags: git, svn

I try to use 'git svn dcommit' but got these errors:

A repository hook failed: 'pre-commit' hook failed with error output:

```
*** Transaction blocked
    TRAILING WHITESPACE discovered in these files
        designs/trunk/1167923/cfg/main.cpp
        designs/trunk/1167923/cfg/Registers.cpp

Code does not conform to whitespace standard
 at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 922
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my configuration:

```
receive.denynonfastforwards=true
alias.st=status
alias.ci=commit
alias.co=checkout
alias.br=branch
alias.log1=log --oneline
alias.fetchavs=fetch --all --progress -v
alias.pushav=push --all --progress -v
alias.dfb=diff -b 
alias.dfw=diff -w
color.ui=auto
color.branch=auto
color.diff=auto
color.interactive=auto
color.status=auto
core.autocrlf=input
core.safecrlf=true
core.whitespace=nowarn
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
svn-remote.svn.url=http://svn
svn-remote.svn.fetch=designs/trunk/1167923:refs/remotes/trunk
svn-remote.svn.branches=designs/branches/1167923/*:refs/remotes/*
svn-remote.svn.tags=designs/tags/1167923/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Comment: Having just looked at your existing questions - Please review them vote for any answers you like and *accept* some answers.

Answer (score 2):

That error is going to be coming from your remote (svn) server - your git-svn config isn't particularly relevant.

You'll need to edit the commits you have pending so that each individual commit is accepted by the server.

E.g.

- `git rebase -i HEAD~10`
- identify the problem commit
- select e for edit
- correct your whitespace error
- `git commit -va --amend`
- `git rebase --continue`

And then try to `dcommit` again.

It will be in your interest to put equivalent checks in your own git pre-commit hook - so that you can know at the time of committing that your changes will be rejected when pushed to svn, and therefore can be corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't tried it yet. But I got I think can't understand. If it is the issue from remote (svn) server, why I can check in the same file with `svn commit` command?

Comment: `git svn dcommit` will submit each of your commits, one at a time, to svn - you didn't commit the file in exactly the same state as the failed commit. ALT look at `/usr/lib/git-core/git-svn` line 922 - that's probably the line where git performs the svn command. ALT2 - add some empty lines to your cpp files and try and commit them directly to svn - compare the error messages.